# when using jquery dialog, how do you call functions when populating via ajax

Tags: jquery, dialog, asmselect

i am trying to get asmSelect, which works fine on its own:

http://www.ryancramer.com/projects/asmselect/examples/example1.html

but i am now trying to get it to work on a page that get dynamically populated into a jquery UI dialog popup but it doesn't seem to be working.  I am basically mimicing the code below and rendering a partialresult inside of a dialog.

http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2009/06/rendering-modal-dialog-with-aspnet-mvc.html

i guess my question is when you are loading stuff dynamically through ajax, this code in asmSelect doesn't seem to work as the code isn't there yet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[multiple]").asmSelect();
    });
 </script>
```

where can i put this ?  do i need to shove all of the jquery references and this code into the usercontrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code copies [this tutorial](http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2009/06/rendering-modal-dialog-with-aspnet-mvc.html), you would want to add your `.asmSelect()` call after the  `$('#container').append(htmlResult);` call like this (Just the `get` sample shown here):

```
$.get(
    "Home/RandomPopupView",
    function( htmlResult ){
        $('#RandomModal').remove();
        $('#container').append( htmlResult );
        $("#container select[multiple]").asmSelect();
        $('#RandomModal').dialog();
    });
```